# Juju Local failed with /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory

Tags: juju, dbus

I am following steps from juju startup with lcx.

At first step of juju bootstrap it gives error as:

> ERROR juju.provider.local environ.go:435 could not install mongo
>   service: exec ["start" "--system" "juju-db-xxxx-local"]: exit status 1
>   (start: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket
>   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory)

mongo db service as such works fine no errors also command which is trying to run is executing successfully

```
service juju-db-xxxxx-local start
juju-db-xxxxx-local start/running, process 8734
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Found this question:

[juju bootstrap fails on local environment - Could not install mongo service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400612/juju-bootstrap-fails-on-local-environment-could-not-install-mongo-service)

```
sudo apt-get install dbus
```

Comment: Thanks, However it says dbus is already the newest version., I could also run mongodb standalone it works as expected.

This looks more like issue of user juju is using to start service, However not able to solve it.

Comment: I removed dbus and install it again, and it started working :)