# juju bootstrap fails on local environment - Could not install mongo service

Tags: server, juju, mongodb

I'm attempting to use JuJu install for the first time. I created a 12.04 guest VM just for this process and I'm getting an error when I try an complete the bootstrap process
sudo juju bootstrap

ERROR could not install mongo service: exec ["start" "--system" "juju-db-david-local"]: exit status 1 (start: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory)
ERROR exec ["start" "--system" "juju-db-david-local"]: exit status 1 (start: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory)

I'm following the instructions from here:

https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html

https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-LXC.html

One google search mentioned an issue relating to disk space. I have plenty. Other ideas?

Comment: Turns out dbus was not installed.

`sudo apt-get install dbus`

Solved my problem.

Comment: Is it all good now? If it is, put your comment above as your answer then at least the question will be shown as answered :-)

Answer (score 2):

OP posted:

Turns out dbus was not installed.  `sudo apt-get install dbus` Solved my problem.